# PHP gettext Simplified Chinese support?

Tags: php, gettext, chinese-locale, php-gettext

I'm trying to support traditional chinese in one of my PHP projects, but I can't get it to show any chinese characters. Here's my gettext setup:

```
putenv("LC_ALL=zh_CN.utf8");
setlocale(LC_ALL, "zh_CN.utf8");
bindtextdomain("wpsmessages", dirname(__FILE__) . "/locale");
bind_textdomain_codeset("wpsmessages", 'UTF-8');
textdomain("wpsmessages");
```

Earlier I created the locale in SSH by typing:

```
sudo locale-gen zh_CN.utf8
```

Which then returned:

```
Generating locales...
zh_CN.UTF-8... done
```

After typing `locale -a` I get the follwing in the list (among others):

```
zh_CN
zh_CN.utf8
```

But still, it doesn't show any chinese characters. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't too clear about this. So I basically have a gettext ready PHP project calling `__('This is some text')`, getting the text from .mo and .po files residing in a `/locale/` folder. gettext is working fine for locales de_DE.utf8, nl_NL.utf8, pt_BR.utf8 etc, but I can't get it to print the strings for simplified chinese. Instead, it prints the english default strings.

Comment: Hey Jake, I'm not using WordPress, but the PHP gettext functions (http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.gettext.php) using the config I posted in my initial post. What gets me wondering is that gettext is working fine for several locales in my project, but it refuses to work for simplified chinese. I'm not even sure if `zh_CN.utf8` is the correct locale. Maybe `zh_CN.GB2312` (where GB2312 is the encoding) is the correct one, but I tried both, neither worked. My `wpsmessages-zh_CN.mo` file seems correct to me.

Comment: Damnit, sorry to have wasted your time with this, but the issue was a file name convention issue. The `wpsmessages-zh_CN.mo` should have been named `wpsmessages.mo`, but you couldn't know that. Please delete this topic, burn it, burn me, whatever you like. :) This is embarrassing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little emberrassing, but the solution was simply renaming the file `wpsmessages-zh_CN.mo` to `wpsmessages.mo` following my own file name conventions.

Basically the structure of my PHP project using gettext is like this:

```
/locale/pt_BR.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/wpsmessages.mo
/locale/zh_CN.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/wpsmessages.mo
...
```

So using `bindtextdomain("wpsmessages", dirname(__FILE__) . "/locale");` gets the correct `.mo` file for a locale specified by `setlocale()`, but it couldn't find the file as it's name was wrong.

Hope this helps anyone being as stupid as me. :)